# Any way to make double click select more than one word without Javascript?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a web page which contains command line commands for the user to copy paste. Any way to display it with HTML/CSS which makes double clicking on one word select the entire command?

Example: `ls -l /myfiles` - clicking on "myfiles" here selects only that word, but for the user it'd be a better experience if the entire command was selected for easier copy-pasting. Again: No javascript is the question here.

Comment: this is impossible without custom (java)scripting since you need to modify the default behaviour of your browser.

Comment: No, changing behaviour in the browsers is the purview of JavaScript; though you may be able to do it at the OS level somehow.

Comment: @kasperTaeymans yes so the reason in fact is that there is no such default behavior on browser :) ... except the tripple-click mentioned by mvryan answer

Comment: For my curiosity, why do you reject the js solution ? To enable this feature for users that run their browsing disabling it ? Or an other reason ?

Comment: I agree with Rémi. If you want to enhance user experience then why you wouldn't use javascript? There isn't a better experience then clicking a string once and copy it to the clipboard at the same time/automatically. Obviously you need javascript for this.

Comment: found a solution for this! check my answer.

Comment: @remibecheras The reason is I'm writing on a blog service which prohibits Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't any way to do that **for a double click**  without javascript.

The default browser behavior is the only behavior available without javascript.

- Tripple-click will works to select a single line.
- If you want to select a different pattern, you need javascript.
- If you only want this behavior on double-click, you need javascript.

Answer (score 4):

I commented in the question that selecting multiple words by double clicking is not possible without javascript. This is not totally true at least for firefox. I just found a way that will select multiple words by double clicking the first word!

You need to use a space followed by unicode `&#x200f;` (right-to-left mark)

Only works in Firefox!

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/goz04n3a/1/)

OR double click 'Hello' in the block qoute for demo.

> Hello ‏my ‏name ‏is ‏Kasper

I don't know why this is working. I was just experimenting with unicodes... More info can be found on w3.org:

[Using a Unicode right-to-left mark (RLM) or left-to-right mark (LRM) to mix text direction inline](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H34.html)

EDIT:

Using other unicode space characters may be closer to the behaviour you want. For example unicode `&#8200;` DEMO ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/goz04n3a/4/)) OR double click any word in the block quote below (again, only works in firefox)

> Hello my name is Kasper

other example (double click on a word with capitals)

> in this SENTENCE ONLY WORDS WITH capitals are
>   selected

Comment: just tested it in Chrome and IE and it doesn't work indeed. However I wouldn't use this technique like stated in the comments of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Would they be able to just triple click? You can select an entire element with that, or to limit it put in breaks.

This would keep expected highlighting behavior consistent.

Comment: What do you mean with "put in breaks"? Is there any way to make it *not* select the entire line, but only a portion of it with triple click?

Comment: It selects at least a line. It will highlight a whole p tag by default and if you want to stop it you can insert a br tag to break it up.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the CSS property `user-select: all;` would allow to select the whole element using a **single** click: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_user-select.asp